# Relationship between "detrimental" and "effective"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, connotations, ielts

A sample IELTS question in the reading section concerns a passage about how dentistry has improved over the last few centuries.  The passage includes:

> "...for most of the 18th and the beginning of the 19th century...Barber-surgeons didn't just remove teeth, either: they also doled out detrimental advice on how to care for teeth and relieve toothache - suggesting, for instance, that patients pick their gums with the beak of an osprey bird."

The question asks:

> Does the following statement reflect the claims of the writer? Answer
>   **YES** if the statement reflects the claims of the writer
>   **NO** if the statement contradicts the claims of the writer
>   **NOT GIVEN** if it is impossible to say what the writer thinks about this.

The statement is:

> Picking one's gums with the bill of an osprey was an effective method of pain relief in the 19th century.

The official correct answer is **YES**.  The explanation cites the quoted text above, starting after the colon, with "sooth an aching tooth" substituted for "relieve toothache."

I would have thought the answer would be **NO** because of the adjective "detrimental" indicating the writer did not think the advice was effective.

Is there a positive relationship between these two adjectives that would make the answer **YES**?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a relationship between the two words which would make the answer **yes** without interpretation.

The writer may be assuming that using ***detrimental*** forms a *contrast* between the potential long-term *hazards* and the short-term *relief*.

It seems the point of the question is *reading comprehension*, but it appears to be a poorly posed question.  From the text we have

> they also doled out detrimental advice on how to care for teeth and relieve toothache - suggesting, for instance, that patients pick their gums with the beak of an osprey bird.

We actually **only** know that it was ***detrimental*** advice, we don't really know how ***effective*** it was for pain relief.

Answer (score 0):

The stated answer is simply *incorrect*.  You cannot claim that something is "detrimental" and then assert it was nevertheless *effective*.  That's a flat-out contradiction.

At best, the answer should be NOT GIVEN, since it doesn't say whether *picking one's teeth with a bird* actually works to relieve pain.

Either "detrimental" is a mistake (and the passage should have used some other word like "salutary"), or you should discard this question as invalid.